Does raydium V2 SDK have derive helpers for PDAs
Does the Raydium V2 SDK have helpers to derive PDA address for example for the pool_id -> https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-clmm/blob/119ed36bf9f33335ed8d671780502bc37d9f1605/programs/amm/src/instructions/create_pool.rs#L17-L29

You can import the method directly from @raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2
import { getPdaPoolId } from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2";

This is where the function is defined -> https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2/blob/c6c38a6a3fd3390fad0506d08096a6f45afc4add/src/raydium/clmm/utils/pda.ts#L27-L37
export function getPdaPoolId(
  programId: PublicKey,
  ammConfigId: PublicKey,
  mintA: PublicKey,
  mintB: PublicKey,
): {
  publicKey: PublicKey;
  nonce: number;
} {
  return findProgramAddress([POOL_SEED, ammConfigId.toBuffer(), mintA.toBuffer(), mintB.toBuffer()], programId);
}

